# Rodrigues equation VS Hamilton's quaternions. Historical confusion.

Tags: vectors, rotations, quaternions, cross-product

I don't have a special math education and when I study quaternions I spent a long time.
Along the way, without realizing, I independently derived the Rodrigues equation, because now we know about the cross-production of vectors. I was very surprised that in all mathematical libraries instead of a complex product of quaternions under the name "quaternions" they use this simple and understandable equation.

But there is some misunderstanding...

This equation was derived by Rodriguez three years before Hamilton quaternions, **BUT** in this equation used vector cross-production, and as I later found out, **they come from quaternions**! This is a little confusing.

So what was invented first? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: "A then B" can be interpreted as a **temporal** relationship (historical approach) : "A appears before B". But it is frequently taken in the reverse order "B then A" where 'then' is a **logical** ordering (B has been presented first, then A has been established from B). This situation occurs very frequently.

Comment: Well, history is never simple... You might be interested in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00595376) by Jeremy J. Gray about Rodrigues's paper.

Comment: @HansLundmark Thank you for the link!